# AlarmManager не работает после завершения приложения

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager

Использую `AlarmManager` для того, чтобы вызвать `BroadcastReceiver`. Устанавливаю его в одной из активити приложения. После завершения приложения `AlarmManager` не срабатывает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить проблему.
Под "завершением приложения" имею в виду не его сворачивание (например, через кнопку `home`), а именно завершение, скажем, через стандартный тасккилер.

Пробовал `.set()` `.setExact()` `.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` Также пробовал добавить приложение в whitelist батареи.

Использование именно `AlarmManager` не обязательно, нужно просто запустить задачу через заданное время.

При тестировании использую устройство с API 23

P.S.: будильники же как-то работают :D

Comment: Разве в Андроиде есть "стандартный тасккилер" ?!

Comment: @woesss Прошу прощения, если использовал неправильный термин, поправьте меня, если (наверняка) я ошибаюсь :)
Если нажать на аппаратную кнопку для просмотра недавних приложений, откроется "менюшка" с окошками. Обычно внизу этой "менюшки" есть несколько кнопок, одна из которых убирает все окошки. В своём описании проблемы я имел в виду этот случай.

Comment: https://github.com/evernote/android-job в зависимости от версии девайса использует AlarmManager, GCM или JobScheduler. Берите и не мучайте себя. ЗЫ Будильники работают, потому что они системные.